# How to remove unnecessary line breaks in data before writing to CSV

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is store a bunch of information into a .csv 
file.After running the script and getting all the email addresses into a csv file I notice the following problem. Around cell CE the row breaks and a new row is being created. Sometimes the row ends up breaking in the middle of an email address.
Practical example:

email, name@email.com, name@email.com, name@email.com, name@em

ail.com, name@email.com, name@email.com, name@email.com, name@email.c

om, name@email.com, name@email.com, name@email.com, name@
email.com]

I also need to mention that Im trying to pull 20k contacts with this script.

```
import requests
import csv
import unicodedata
import getpass

# Credentials
url = 'https://....com/api/v2/users.json'
csvfile = 'users2.csv'

output_3 = []
output_3.append("email")

while url:

    # Use Your Sign-On Credentials
user = '...'
pwd = '...'
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))
data = response.json()

for user in data['users']:
    email = user['email']
    decode_3 = bool(email) and unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', email)
    output_3.append(decode_3)

print(data['next_page'])
url = 'https://.../api/v2/users.json' and data['next_page']
print("users:")
print(len(output_3))

# Write to a csv file
with open((csvfile), mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow([output_3])
```

Comment: Is there a CR or LF in the fields? Maybe you could just trim the fields before writing them.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your `output_3` list is fed content containing whitespace or line break characters. You could try stripping your mail of trailing whitespaces `str.strip()` or to manually remove whitespace characters (`str.replace('\n', '')` or `str.replace(' ', '')`).